# Activity UI not responds after opening with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, android-activity

I am working on one music application and I am really stucked with one scenario here and desparatly needs help for this, The scenario is below,

I have one Home Activity from here the user can play a song.

I have one Music Activity from here also user can play song.
I have music controls like play, pause, shuffle and repeat in Music Activity.

A user can switch from home to music and music to home so I am opening the activity with **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** so the activity state is saved.

And I have used the ExoPlayer for playing the song and manage the notification foreground service to show the music controls.
Now the issue is,

User goes to Music activity and plays a song now User goes to home activity and play a song from there. After this user comes back to music the song is playing because of the foreground service. But when a user clicks on play/pause button the UI of that button is not getting updated.

Functionality is working but the UI does not seem to respond anymore.

Does anyone has faced this issue?
Please let me know the solution or workaround.

**Note: I need to keep the state of both activities so I cant user intent flags like CLEAR_TOP or CLEAR_TASK.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better make use of fragments instead of Activity.

Comment: Yes i have used fragments, but Because of my app's design and structure, i need to have this two activity as parent activity for two different modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the launchMode for both activities as `singleInstance` in AndroidManifest file.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: If i use the single instance than the stack will not be managed.